# React js and spring boot : axios error 400 with postmapping and two parameter

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, parameters, axios

I am trying to send two constant variable from my onSubmit method but I get error 400

> POST http://localhost:8080/MenuFiltre/filtreregioncloser 400

Code React js :

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const FilterClassification = {
      // classification
      rfx: this.state.rfx,
      rfp: this.state.rfp,
      rfp_x: this.state.rfp_x,
      allclassification: this.state.allclassification
    };
    const FilterRegion = {
      //Region
     eu : this.state.eu,
    americas  : this.state.americas,
    aae : this.state.aae,
    ger: this.state.ger,
    eu2 : this.state.eu2,
    latam : this.state.latam,
    empty : this.state.empty,
    allregion : this.state.allregion,
    }
    console.log(FilterRegion);
    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/MenuFiltre/filtreregioncloser",FilterClassification , FilterRegion )
  }
```

Spring boot code :

```
@PostMapping("/filtreregioncloser")
    public Iterable<Closerfprfx>gettab1(@RequestBody  FilterClassification FilterClassification  , @RequestBody  FilterRegion FilterRegion) 
    {
        
//GET CLASSIFICATION 

            boolean rfx = FilterClassification.isRfx();
            String ChaineRfx = "";
            if(rfx==true)
            {
                ChaineRfx="rfx";
            }else
            {
                ChaineRfx="xxxx";
            }
            boolean rfp =FilterClassification.isRfp() ;
            String ChaineRfp = "";
            if(rfp == true)
            {
                ChaineRfp="rfp";
            }else
            {
                ChaineRfp="xxxx";
            }
            boolean rfp_x= FilterClassification.isRfp_x();
            String ChaineRfp_x = "";
            if(rfp_x==true)
            {
                ChaineRfp_x="rfp_x";
            }else
            {
                ChaineRfp_x="xxxx";
            }
            boolean allclassification = FilterClassification.isAllclassification() ;
            
            
               boolean eu = FilterRegion.isEu();
               String ChaineEu= "";
               if(eu==true)
               {
                   ChaineEu="eu";
               }else
               {
                   ChaineEu="xxxx";
               }
               boolean  americas = FilterRegion.isAmericas();
               String ChaineAmericas = "";
               if(americas==true)
               {
                   ChaineAmericas="americas";
               }
               else {
                   ChaineAmericas="xxxx";
               }
               boolean  aae = FilterRegion.isAae();
               String ChaineAae = "";
               if(aae==true)
               {
                   ChaineAae="aae";
               }else {
                   ChaineAae="xxxx";
               }
               boolean  ger = FilterRegion.isGer();
               String ChaineGer="";
               if(ger==true)
               {
                   ChaineGer="ger";
                   
               }else
               {
                   ChaineGer="xxxx";
               }
               boolean  eu2 = FilterRegion.isEu2();
               String ChaineEu2="";
               if(eu2=true)
               {
                   ChaineEu2="eu2";
               }else {
                   ChaineEu2="xxxx";
               }
               boolean  latam = FilterRegion.isLatam() ;
               String ChaineLatam = "";
               if(latam=true)
               {
                   ChaineLatam="latam";
                   }else {
                   ChaineLatam="xxxx";
               }
               boolean  empty = FilterRegion.isEmpty();
               String ChaineEmpty="";
               if(empty=true)
               {
                   ChaineEmpty="empty";
               }else {
                   ChaineEmpty="xxxx";
               }
               boolean  allregion = FilterRegion.isAllregion();
               
                return null;      
    }
```

please what i should to do now i need to resolve my error please ! the first parameter works fine without error but when I try to add a second parameter I get error 400

Answer (score 0):

A post request accepts one `RequestBody` you can't send multiple request bodies.

the axios api is the following

`axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`

which means that the first parameter is the `url` the second is `data` the third is a `config` object that configurates how axios should send the request.

all this is written in [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios) which you could of easily googled if you put some effort in.

The solution is simple, Place your objects in a wrapper object.

```js
axios.post("url", {
    classification: {
       ...
    },
    region: {
       ...
    }
});
```

In your java code

```java
public class FilterRequest {

   private Classification classification;
   private Region region;

   //constructor getters setters etc.
 
}

@PostMapping("/filtreregioncloser") // <-- This is a horrible endpoint name and it is misspelled
public Iterable<Closerfprfx>gettab1(@RequestBody FilterRequest filterRequest) 
{
    final Classification classification = filterRequest.getClassification();
    final Region region = filterRequest.getRegion();
}
```